# justify align for rtl text on react-native

Tags: react-native

How could I align the RTL text to justify on react-native? As the react-native website says we could set align of text to `'auto', 'left', 'right', 'center', 'justify'` but the `justify` one is not working on RTL text.

Comment: You mean to vertically align the text or horizontally ?

Comment: Please add some code to show what you have tried so far. There is a [blog post](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/next/#making-an-app-rtl-ready) about RTL support in react native. Have you done all the required thing in your app to support RTL?

Comment: this is the screenshot of my app that the text is not being justify. http://karjoo.plus/images/karjooplus3.jpeg

Answer (score 4):

text justify not support in react native **android** native. but there is a trick that you justify your text with `WebView` Component...

here is a sample code:

```
 <WebView
      source={{
        html:
          "<style>p{text-align:justify}</style>" +
          "<p>" +
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus commodo tortor ut ipsum pharetra sodales. Praesent sed diam non lacus convallis dapibus. Sed vulputate erat risus, ac hendrerit eros egestas id. Etiam pellentesque auctor ipsum, non cursus nisi gravida sed. Ut eget pretium risus. Curabitur a lectus odio. Etiam felis urna, pharetra ut odio in, tristique suscipit tortor. Cras vitae risus odio. Etiam a leo elit. Duis molestie fermentum mi vitae pretium. Morbi luctus semper quam, et suscipit nisi convallis dictum. Fusce sit amet est dapibus, interdum ante non, lacinia metus. Donec at nulla non ante consectetur vulputate. Cras tristique porttitor ligula quis posuere. Integer nec laoreet felis, at tempor leo. Ut et convallis quam." +
          "</p>"
      }}
    />
```

if you want call your body texts from your server compile to html and use your source in it (this is not a good but only way)

Comment: and if u find a way tag me ( eshghi dada )